# Redirect to route not redirecting in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've been using `Laravel-5.8.35`. I was invoking a `GET` request through a form. On my route, I redirected the `form` action to the same `controller`  where the form was submitted but redirected through a different route, as,

```
$router->get('/merchant/sd-refund', 'Reports\ReportController@refundSecurityDeposit');
```

And, in my `refundSecurityDeposit` method, I called my `SohojSdRefundService` service,

```
    public function refundSecurityDeposit(Request $request)
    {
        // $userId, $reason, $sdAmount was fetched from the $request instance
        $this->execRefundRequest($userId, $reason, $sdAmount);
    }

    public function execRefundRequest($userId, $reason, $sdAmount)
    {
        // here the API service request data was handled,
        // and stored in $data instance

        return SohojSdRefundService::callSdRefundApi($data);
    }
```

While my `SohojSdRefundService` service was done handling, I wanted to redirect the route to another route, as,

```
class SohojSdRefundService
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public static function callSdRefundApi($requestData)
    {
        // call to other methods inside the class to handle the API response,
        // and then return to the same route which isn't working

        return redirect('/admin/merchant/list');
    }
}
```

Respectively, instead of redirecting to that route, the page happens to be still on the `/merchant/sd-refund?...` where the `form` was submitted initially. I redirected another service like this, which is working fine though. Could anyone suggest what I could be implementing wrong here? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a result in refundSecurityDeposit fucntion

```
public function refundSecurityDeposit(Request $request)
{

   return $this->execRefundRequest($userId, $reason, $sdAmount);
}
```